# Can I simplify this portion of pandas code

Tags: pandas, max, min

I would like to simplify this portion of the code if at all possible. Any assistance is appreciated.

```
min_closing = df['AAPL.Close'].min()

max_closing = df['AAPL.Close'].max()

min_closing_date = df[df['AAPL.Close']==min_closing]

max_closing_date = df[df['AAPL.Close']==max_closing]

print("Min closing price {} on {}".format(min_closing, min_closing_date.iloc[0,0])) 

print("Max closing price {} on {}".format(max_closing, max_closing_date.iloc[0,0]))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can with `idxmin` and `idxmax`

```
idmin = df['AAPL.Close'].idxmin()
print("Min closing price {} on {}".format(df.loc[idmin, 'AAPL.Close'], df.loc[idmin, 'Date']))
```

If Date is index , `idmin` is the min date

```
print("Min closing price {} on {}".format(df.loc[idmin, 'AAPL.Close'], idmin))
```

Comment: Can this be modified if 'date' has been set as the index?